# Produce a NestedHstore hash with Rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, puma, hstore

I have a field called `custom` that is defined as a NestedHstore:

```
# project.rb
serialize :custom, ActiveRecord::Coders::NestedHstore
```

I create fixtures for this model for testing:

```
one:
  company: one
  user: one
  custom:
    :name:
      :prompt: 'What is your name?'
```

When this is run, the nested hashes are saved as strings, i.e. `@project.custom = {"name"=>"{:prompt=>\"What is your name?\"}"}`

I've gotten around this in unit and functional tests by adding a `prepare_custom` method that manually reconstructs the nested hash from the string BEFORE anything runs.

```
  def prepare_custom(p)
    if p.custom.present?
      if p.custom.is_a? Hash
        p.custom.each do |k,v|
          if (v.class == String) && (v[0] == "{") && (v[-1] == "}")
            p.custom[k] = eval(v)
          end
        end
      end
      p.save
      p.reload
      puts "*** project: #{p.inspect}"
    end
  end
```

When I run integration tests (with Capybara/Poltergeist/Puma), this happens:

1. `prepare_custom(@project)` seems to work. `p.inspect` at the end shows that custom is a properly nested hash.
2. The integration test code that runs immediately after `prepare_custom` seems to completely ignore that the project has been changed. It thinks `p.custom[:name]` is a string again.

How can I either get fixtures to save the nested hash properly, or get my integration tests to reflect the work done in `prepare_custom`?

---

#### Follow-up

After trying: `custom: <%= {name: { prompt: 'What is your name?'}}.to_yaml.inspect %>` in the fixture, we get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near ':' at position 4
    LINE 1: ...company_id") VALUES ('Simple prompt', 0, '---
                                                                       ^
    : INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "custom", "created_at", "updated_at", "id", "company_id") VALUES ('Simple prompt', '---
    :name:
      :prompt: What is your name?
    ', '2017-05-17 21:15:25', '2017-05-17 21:15:25', 159160234, 980190962, 159160234)
```

Comment: try `custom: <%= {name: { prompt: 'What is your name?'}}.to_yaml.inspect  %>` in your fixture file

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I get: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near ':' at position 4` - the rest added to the question.

Comment: @sscirrus did you ever find a solution? Facing this problem myself.